# Convert function parameter in string into parameter in object

Tags: javascript, node.js, function-parameter

I am using node.js.

I have a function that can be called this way;

```
add_row({location:'L1', row_name:'r1', value:'18.4'});
```

I have a string like this;

```
var str_param = "location:'L1', row_name:'r1', value:'18.4'";
```

I tried to do something like this to keep my code simple;

```
add_row(str_param);
```

It did not work. What is a good way to use `str_param` to call `add_row`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the string to an object that the function accepts.

```
function toObj(str) {
  const a = str.split(/,.?/g);
  return a.reduce((p, c) => {
    const kv = c.replace(/'/g, '').split(':');
    p[kv[0]] = kv[1];
    return p;
  }, {});
}

toObj(str); // { location: "L1", row_name: "r1", value: "18.4" }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/59un0kc0/5/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be your issue:

```
{location:'L1', row_name:'r1', value:'18.4'} // Object
var str_param = "location:'L1', row_name:'r1', value:'18.4'"; // Not object

var str_param = "{location:'L1', row_name:'r1', value:'18.4'}"; // Object String
```

I do not use Node JS but just taking a shot in dark. If not you could just make function like:

```
function addRow(pLocation, pRowName, pValue) {
    var row = {
        location: pLocation,
        row_name: pRowName,
        value: pValue
    }

    // Logic ....
}
```

If that does not work try using Object string and look at function ParseJSON I believe it's called.