# JavaScript parsing a string to object

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I am working a parsing part to parse the string value to a string to an object.

I thought a way to do this is calling `substr()` for several times, but if there is any way to do it more clearly？

For example, when I input the string

```
USER='Howe', TEXT='foo'
```

or

```
USER='HOWE' TEXT='foo'
```

or

```
USER='HOWE',TEXT='foo'
```

After the function, an object would be like this:

```
{USER:'HOWE, TEXT='foo'};
```

Comment: I'm little confused. Are you saying you want to group multiple occurrences of `USER` and `TEXT` into an array of objects for each? so `USER='HOWE',TEXT='foo',USER='2',TEXT='3'` would be `[{USER: 'HOWE', TEXT: 'foo'}, {USER: '2', TEXT: '3'}]`

Comment: Can you clarify on this? Do you want to add a string to an array using array.push(string); or change the value of an entry in an object with object.property = string; ?

Comment: Sorry guys, just edit the question, I want to parse a string to an object with index and property, thank you. @ste2425

Comment: [I answered a similar question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023792/convert-function-parameter-in-string-into-parameter-in-object/37024381#37024381)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reworked from [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37023792/convert-function-parameter-in-string-into-parameter-in-object/37024381#37024381).

```
function toObj(str) {
  const a = str.split(/[,\s]+/);
  return a.reduce((p, c) => {
    const kv = c.replace(/'/g, '').split('=');
    p[kv[0]] = kv[1];
    return p;
  }, {});
}

toObj("USER='Howe', TEXT='foo'"); // { USER: "Howe", TEXT: "foo" }
toObj("USER='Howe',TEXT='foo'"); // { USER: "Howe", TEXT: "foo" }
toObj("USER='Howe' TEXT='foo'"); // { USER: "Howe", TEXT: "foo" }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/59un0kc0/6/)

Answer (score 1):

That's not quite valid object syntax for JSON. You could do it like this:

```
var text = '{ "USER":"Howe", "TEXT":"foo" }';
var obj = JSON.parse(text);
console.log(text, obj);
```

Then you can simply refer to the properties via `obj.USER` and `obj.TEXT`.

**EDITED: after discussion...**

I'd suggest doing something like the following, if you wish to give users the ability to search on two fields (you can extend this for as many fields as you wish, of course).

```
<script>
function search() {
    var userValue = document.getElementById('txtUser').value;
    var textValue = document.getElementById('txtText').value;
    var jsonText = '{ "USER":"' + userValue + '", "TEXT":"' + textValue + '" }';
    console.log(jsonText);
    var json = JSON.parse(jsonText);
    console.log(json);

    // Do whatever you wish with your created object here...
}
</script>

<input id="txtUser" value="foo" type="text">
<input id="txtText" value="bar" type="text">
<button onclick="search();">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Well the string is actually for a user to do the search function. So I don't expect a user would type such syntax as the JSON syntax..

Comment: All you require then is to grab the values from the user and to construct the JSON text yourself. Don't make your users enter text like that. Two text boxes, grab the values, construct the JSON text, parse it, job done :)

Comment: Well the thing is I am implementing a search module for my web app, and there is a search bar just like Twitter, and I want to support a advanced searching function.. That is why I ask this question.. I know your suggestion is a better solution.. But I am no an experienced JavaScript coder, so..

Comment: You don't need to be an experienced JS coder. You only need to implement some basic HTML, then construct the string like I've specified above e.g. `var jsonText = '{ "USER":"' + userValue + '", "TEXT":"' + textValue + '" }';`. I'll update my answer with an example for you :) You definitely don't want your users to be typing in that string. But, if you must, then you should parse it first and then create your json from that, then simply parse the json into an object.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. But actually I am going to present this app the day after tomorrow.. So I chose to complete a complex searching text first, then I want to continue developing this app with your idea, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to parse out the keys and values from the input string:

```
function convert(s) {
  var m = s.match(/USER='(.*)'.*TEXT='(.*)'/);
  return {
    USER: m[1],
    TEXT: m[2]
  }
}

console.log(convert("USER='HOWE' TEXT='foo'"));
```

The [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) expression uses grouping (wrapping the "matches" in parenthesis) to capture the values, which then end up in the `m` array.

The `convert` function will return a JavaScript object. If you wish to turn that into a JSON string use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

JSBin: https://jsbin.com/fefufehibo/edit?js,console

Answer (score -1):

If you really just want to split those two values in to an array you could do something like:

```
str.split(',');
```

But it actually sounds like you want to change it to an object with key, value pairs and not an Array at all.

Can you be more specific? What is the exact string you want to parse?

Comment: I just updated the question, what I want is to parse the string to an object with index and key, thank you very much